# Scale bar in QGIS shows incorrect measurements

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping, scale-bar

I am mapping change in share of land used for agricultural use by nation. For some reason when I add the scale bar it displays incorrect measurements (see screenshot attached. I am pretty sure the Indian Ocean from Madagascar to Perth is greater than 5km.

Could this be an issue with the shp file I am using? is there any other info/settings/screenshots I need to provide to get to the bottom of this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are using `WGS84` geographic coordinate reference system (CRS) or any other CRS that uses degrees as a unit of measurement. Therefore, adding a scale bar has no meaning in your layout, as you already discovered when you added one to your map.

The scale bar is useful with projected CRS, such as UTM that uses meter as a unit of measurement.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am a little new with GIS. Is there a way to correct this so I get an accurate scale.

Comment: Accurate scale bar at world scale is questionable. There is always a distortion somehow, but you can have a look at the the following CRSs:https://epsg.io/?q=World%20kind%3APROJCRS and do some testing until you are satisfied with the results.